# Iterate across arbitrary dimension in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional numpy array, and I need to iterate across a given dimension. Problem is, I won't know **which** dimension until runtime. In other words, given an array m, I could want

```
m[:,:,:,i] for i in xrange(n)
```

or I could want

```
m[:,:,i,:] for i in xrange(n)
```

etc.

I imagine that there must be a straightforward feature in numpy to write this, but I can't figure out what it is/what it might be called. Any thoughts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589706/iterating-over-arbitrary-dimension-of-numpy-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating over arbitrary dimension of numpy.array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589706/iterating-over-arbitrary-dimension-of-numpy-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. You could build the right index with a list of slices, or perhaps alter `m`'s strides. However, the simplest way may be to use `np.swapaxes`:

```
import numpy as np
m=np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
print(m.shape)
# (2, 3, 4)
```

Let `axis` be the axis you wish to loop over. `m_swapped` is the same as `m` except the `axis=1` axis is swapped with the last (`axis=-1`) axis.

```
axis=1
m_swapped=m.swapaxes(axis,-1)
print(m_swapped.shape)
# (2, 4, 3)
```

Now you can just loop over the last axis:

```
for i in xrange(m_swapped.shape[-1]):
    assert np.all(m[:,i,:] == m_swapped[...,i])
```

Note that `m_swapped` is a view, not a copy, of `m`.  Altering `m_swapped` will alter `m`.

```
m_swapped[1,2,0]=100
print(m)
assert(m[1,0,2]==100)
```

Comment: Thanks! For the record, .swapaxes() did the trick for what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `slice(None)` in place of the `:`.  For example,

```
from numpy import *

d = 2  # the dimension to iterate

x = arange(5*5*5).reshape((5,5,5))
s = slice(None)  # :

for i in range(5):
    slicer = [s]*3  # [:, :, :]
    slicer[d] = i   # [:, :, i]
    print x[slicer] # x[:, :, i]
```

Comment: +1 This is by far the best solution for generalising to n-dimensional tensors e.g. dimensions of `a1 x a2 x a3 x a4 x ... x an`