# Iterating over 3D numpy using one dimension as iterator remaining dimensions in the loop

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, iterator, numpy-ndarray

Despite there being a number of similar questions related to iterating over a 3D array and after trying out some functions like `nditer` of numpy, I am still confused on how the following can be achieved:

I have a signal of dimensions (30, 11, 300) which is 30 trials of 11 signals containing 300 signal points.

Let this signal be denoted by the variable `x_`

I have another function which takes as input a (11, 300) matrix and plots it on 1 graph (11 signals containing 300 signal points plotted on a single graph). Let this function be `sliding_window_plot`.

Currently, I can get it to do this:

```
x_plot = x_[0,:,:]
for i in range(x_.shape[0]):
    sliding_window_plot(x_plot[:,:])
```

which plots THE SAME (first trial) 11 signals containing 300 points on 1 plot, 30 times. 
I want it to plot the i'th set of signals. Not the first (0th) trial of signals everytime. Any hints on how to attempt this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to iterate over the first dimension with a `for` loop:

```
for s in x_:
    sliding_window_plot(s)
```

with each iteration `s` will be the next array of shape (11, 300).

Comment: TIL numpy arrays are iterables. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In general for all nD-arrays where n>1, you can iterate over the **very first dimension of the array** as if you're iterating over any other iterable. For checking whether an array is an iterable, you can use `np.iterable(arr)`. Here is an example:

```
In [9]: arr = np.arange(3 * 4 * 5).reshape(3, 4, 5) 

In [10]: arr.shape 
Out[10]: (3, 4, 5) 

In [11]: np.iterable(arr) 
Out[11]: True 

In [12]: for a in arr: 
    ...:     print(a.shape) 
    ...:                     
(4, 5)
(4, 5)
(4, 5)
```

So, in each iteration we get a matrix (of shape `(4, 5)`) as output. In total, 3 such outputs constitute the 3D array of shape `(3, 4, 5)`

---

If, for some reason, you want to iterate over other dimensions then you can use `numpy.rollaxis` to move the desired axis to the first position and then iterate over it as mentioned in [iterating-over-arbitrary-dimension-of-numpy-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589706/iterating-over-arbitrary-dimension-of-numpy-array)

---

**NOTE**: Having said that `numpy.rollaxis` is only maintained for backwards compatibility. So, it is recommended to use `numpy.moveaxis` instead for moving the desired axis to the first dimension.

Comment: `rollaxis` is only maintained for backwards compatibility, instead, use of `moveaxis` is encouraged.

Answer (score 2):

You are hardcoding the 0th slice outside the for loop. You need to create `x_plot` to be inside the loop. In fact you can simplify your code by not using `x_plot` at all.

`for i in rangge(x_.shape[0]):
  sliding_window_plot(x_[i])`